# Extra character at end of line on copy\paste

Tags: bug, editor

I  saw a curious effect, that happens during copy\paste.

If you check edits done by Peter Mortensen to code in my answer (link below) you see that he removed some  characters at end of each line that looked like  dash.

[Resolution of parameters in variadic function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50433383/resolution-of-parameters-in-variadic-function/50433517#50433517)

I'm concerned about how those characters got there. The code was copy-pasted from wandbox edit box ( https://wandbox.org/ ) and when I examined resulting text after posting it, I didn't saw those  in my browser, which is latest Chrome on Android. The effect is not reproducible on PC.

Is that some invisible control character and why it appeared only in that situation? Shouldn't SO editor have to trim that down automatically?

Comment: Peter removed some trailing white spaces from your code. In the view the white spaces are struck out; this is why you see some "dashes".

Comment: @honk ah, that explains their invisibility, though not where they came from.  Original didn't had them and I would expect editor trim them anyway. Case is closed, I guess

Comment: If you take a look at [revision 5](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50433517/revisions), then you can clearly see those white spaces in the code. It's just on a few lines, so maybe you actually typed them...